# How to read a table of a contract?

Tags: eosjs

I'm trying to dump all rows of the `sellorder`, `buyorder` and `tmporder` table of the `newdexpublic` smart contract. My code is as the following:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); // node only; not needed in browsers
const { JsonRpc } = require('eosjs');

const api_endpoint = 'https://eos.infstones.io';
const rpc = new JsonRpc(api_endpoint, { fetch });

(async ()=> {
  let response = await rpc.get_table_rows({
    json: true,
    code: 'newdexpublic',
    scope: '...........u1',
    table: 'sellorder',
  });
  console.info(response);

  response = await rpc.get_table_rows({
    json: true,
    code: 'newdexpublic',
    scope: '...........u1',
    table: 'buyorder',
  });
  console.info(response);

  response = await rpc.get_table_rows({
    json: true,
    code: 'newdexpublic',
    scope: 'newdexpublic',
    table: 'temporder',
  });
  console.info(response);
})();
```

The code above returns 3 empty arrays:

```
{ rows: [], more: false }
{ rows: [], more: false }
{ rows: [], more: false }
```

I guess some of my parameters must be incorrect, any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with cleos on the command line?

Comment: Do you have any data in these tables, cus your queries are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the smart contract `newdexpublic` uses a weird string as scope, after I set scope to `...........u1`, I can get data from its tables.